# How to sort the rows in excel based on date if I have a format such as this "Thu Feb 13 16:20:23 +0000 2014"?

Tags: excel

I want to sort the rows of an excel sheet based on one of the columns. i.e. date which is in this format

"Thu Feb 13 16:20:23 +0000 2014"

it needs to be sorted on the basis of year 1st, then the month, then the day, and then the time.. other fields are a mere formality

Can we do this by Conditional Formatting?
If so, what formula should be used?

Comment: More details please. That date is a text or a number formatted like that? What kind of sorting are you looking for?

Comment: is the +0000 the difference to GMT ?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to split the date into columns, then sort through columns. I tried this on Excel 2007.

1. Select the column with your dates. Go to **Data** tab and select
   **Text to Column**
2. Select **Delimited** and click **Next**,
3. Select **Other** and put space in the box next to it. Click **Next** and then **Finish**. This will split your date on
   spaces.
4. Now select the 5 columns with the split date then select
   **Sort** in the **Data** tab,
5. For the **Sort by**, select the column with Year, and select Value for **Sort on** and the order you
   want
6. click **Add Level**, and select the column with Month and
   specify how it should be sorted,
7. click **Add level** again,
   select the column with Day and specify how it should be sorted,
8. click **Add level** again for time....

Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: this is not sorting for time.. is there a way i can d it for time?

Comment: @user3491960 does works on mine. You could try change format for the time column to time. Did you select the Sort On to Value and Order to "Smallest to Largest"?

Comment: Yeah.. how do we merge it back? When I tried doing that using the formula [=A1&" "&B1&" "&C1&" "&D1&" "&E1] .. The time part is getting replaced by a decimal number. How do I make sure I get the time as I wanted instead of that?

Comment: @user3491960 for the time part use `TEXT(cell, "hh:mm:ss")`.